# Can typescript detect short-circuit evaluation automatically?

Tags: typescript

Consider this code:

```
function myFunction( object_argument: {} | {optional_property: string}) {
  const fallback: string = 'Foo'
  return object_argument.optional_property || fallback
}
```

This gives me an error:

> Property 'optional_property' does not exist on type '{} | {
>   optional_property: string; }'. Property 'optional_property' does not
>   exist on type '{}'.

A workaround I found was to add explicit type declaration right before the problematic place like this:

```
function myFunction( object_argument: {} | {optional_property: string}) {
  const fallback: string = 'Foo'
  return (<{optional_property}>object_argument).optional_property || fallback
}
```

From my perspective however it's very obvious that I'm performing a ["short-circuit"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation and therefore existence of "optional_property" is literally optional.

Is it possible to make typescript find this out automatically without the need of implicit declarations?
Should I create a feature request on GitHub?

Comment: You should use actual optional properties: `{optional_property?: string}`

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with short-circuit evaluation.  That just means that the second half of a `||` isn't evaluated if the first half is true.

Comment: Important part short-circuit evaluation here is returning a non-boolean value

Comment: @L1Q: Yes; TypeScript is aware that `||` does not always return boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make object properties optional with a question mark: `{field?: type}`.
So your function will be:

```
function myFunction( object_argument: {optional_property?: string}) {
  const fallback: string = 'Foo'
  return object_argument.optional_property || fallback
}
```

Comment: That's helpful, does it mean typescript does detect short-circuit?

Comment: @L1Q: No; it just means that the property can be `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, I think that fixes my issue anyway 